# Can I keep working on "do X Y times" achievements by replaying missions?

Tags: metro-2033

In Metro 2033 if I repeat missions from the "Load" option can I still work on achievements like "Get 20 kills with a throwing knife" when I finish the campaign. So if I killed 18 people during my play through if I go back to a specific mission can I get 2 kills with a throwing knife and get the achievement? Or do I have to start the game again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, If you start the game again all your stats are wiped. So if you had 18/20 at the end of the game, by replaying a mission or starting again for that instance you have 0/20.